# Adding a new switch with an independent light in an existing circuit - With photos

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have two switches at the bottom of my stairs in the basement. One switch is a three way to the switch at the top of my stairs. The other switch lights a series of lights all connected to the same circuit. One of those lights is in the pantry and what I would like to do is isolate that light from the rest by adding a single pole switch to the room. The switch at the bottom of the stairs would still light up the rest of the lights.

Do I need to run a separate hot from the existing box to the new box where the new switch in the pantry will be for the pantry light.[image: at bottom of stairs looking at existing wall switches and looking into the pantry]
[image: Power wire to existing pantry]
[image: Power wire to existing pantry light]
[image: Inside pantry looking at new switch box]

Comment: Please [edit] your first question instead of asking a new one with more details. Please do add the pictures to the first.

Comment: I added the pictures to the original post. I apologize for the duplicate.
Learning the forum and wont happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you can simply break that light off the circuit and put it on a new switch depends completely on how the power is run.

If the light is fed in the ceiling, then yes you can just add a new switch.
Existing wiring:
[image: wiring diagram fed through light]

With the new switch:
[image: wiring diagram with added new switch]

---

However if the power comes through the existing switch then no you will have to run a new feed to the light. That feed can go through the new switch (shown in the bottom diagram), or straight to the light whichever is easier.
Existing wiring:
[image: Beautiful MS paint wiring diagram]

The new diagram for this scenario:
[image: fed from the new switch]

<sub>Who said MS paint couldn't be used for wiring diagrams...</sub>

Comment: Please show these images to the original post.
Thanks david!